# Method undefined error - Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Here is the code of a number partitions and in the last section I have  trouble, because I can´t get the number parted due to method error.

```
class Num_Part

  def Particiones n     //method for the number partititons
    if n == 1
      return [[1]]
    elsif n < 1
      return [[]]
    end
    Particiones(n)
    listaparticiones = []
    for k in (n)..downto(0)
      cola= Particiones(n) - k
      for x in cola
        particion= [k] + x
      end
      listaparticiones << particion
    end
    return listaparticiones
  end

end

puts "Ingrese el Valor de N: \n" // this is where i ask for the value or the 
n =Integer(gets.chomp)            //number to be parted
lista = Particiones(n)

    print "\n cantidad de particiones: " +String(lista.size)

lista.each do |i|
  print [i]
end
obj = Num_Part.new
obj.Particiones(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

Right here you define an *instance method*

```
class Num_Part

  def Particiones n
```

You call it like a *class method*:

```
Num_Part.Particiones(n)
```

So, either change the definition to `def self.Particiones n` or change the call to `Num_Part.new.Partitiones(n)`.

Just a side note, your names don't follow the conventions. For example methods are usually all lowercase